# How can I iterate over and display the icons in Angular's iconRegistry?

Tags: angular, icons, ngfor

Say I have a set of custom [icons](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api) registered:

```
iconRegistry
    .addSvgIcon('one', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('images/one.svg'))
    .addSvgIcon('two', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('images/two.svg'))
    .addSvgIcon('three', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('images/three.svg'));
```

I'd like to render them in an icon library page. How can I access the registry data in an `*ngFor` structure, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can somehow save the list of the icon names to an array inside the component, then you could loop through it in the template like this,

> component

```
iconList = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

> template

```
<md-icon *ngFor="let iconName of iconList" [svgIcon]="iconName"></md-icon>
```

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, you could start with the list to register these icons using `addSvgIcon` method.

> component

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MdIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.iconList.forEach((iconName) => {
     iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        iconName,
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/img/examples/' + iconName + '.svg'));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm hoping to avoid having to manage a separate list. Maybe I should create the list and loop through it to register the icons.

Comment: yeah, was going to suggest that. :) That should work too

Comment: There is also this method, `addSvgIconInNamespace` to add the icons to a nameSpace. But I am not sure how to extract the icon names from it :)

Comment: If you console.log on `this` property, may be you might get some hints on how to make use of that option to get the list of names registered under it.

Comment: Updated my answer as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have built your iconRegistry inside your constructor as recommended:

**component.ts**

```
iconList = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.iconRegistry['_svgIconConfigs'].forEach( (value, key) => {
    this.iconList.push(key.slice(1));
  });
}
```

**component.html**

```
<md-icon *ngFor="let iconName of iconList" [svgIcon]="iconName"></md-icon>
```

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1aGJzrRdQKtNhKPUYdbs?p=preview) with demo svg to show it in action.